# What is the alternative to Oracle JDBC's CallableStatement getParameterMetaData().getParameterType()?

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

The following code throws an exception:

```
CallableStatement cs = ...
cs.getParameterMetaData().getParameterType( columnIndex );

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterType(OracleParameterMetaData.java:166)
    ... 26 more
```

What's the alternative way of getting the parameter type?

Comment: Why do you need to know the parameter type (in a dynamic fashion, too)? Is it to convert types before calling the statement? If so, you could try to call it with `setObject` and hope Oracle can convert it itself.

Comment: We're building a utility that detects any ResultSet from all parameters and do something about it and return it. Where it is set is not known ahead.

Comment: You mean an OUT parameter that ends up being a ResultSet? Does Oracle even do that? Would that be a REFCURSOR?

Comment: Yes, it's an OUT parameter and yes, oracle does that and it works. But since we want this to be dynamic, I need the method's functionality. It's actually SYS_REFCURSOR.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone can provide a better answer to this, I'll accept yours. So here's my answer to my own question.

```
CallableStatement cs = ...
for( int i = 1; i <= cs.getParameterMetaData().getParameterCount(); i++) {
    try {
        // because cs.getParameterMetaData().getParameterType( i ) is not supported by ojdbc, we let this throw SQLException
        Object o = cs.getObject(i);
        if( o instanceof ResultSet ) {
            rs = (ResultSet)o;
        }
    } catch( SQLException sqle ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

It doesn't precisely answer my question but it partially solves my problem.